# Creality Ender 3 after normal printing, lost the ability to print in X and Z axis

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, z-axis, x-axis

Everything worked normally until the printer finished with a model after a 22-hour print job. As usual, I made everything like for the previous models to print the next one, but I suddenly noticed that this time it was printing only to the left side, the coordinates of Y-axis. I tried to change some parameters, opened and cleaned the nozzle from the PLA, powered it on-and-off to rest, checked everything, and performed some research on the net and youtube but it's still the same.

Additionally, I'm sharing this photo as an example of the current situation, with labeling that works only in Y-axis:

[image: A photo from an earlier print. Labeling says, it only moves the bed.]

Any suggestions, or solutions if someone has had the problem before?

Comment: do you print the same g-code or a different one?

Comment: It's the same problem with the existing .gcode and different one.

Comment: Could you share a photo of the result and the G-code that was previously working?

Comment: Yes, here's updated version of the post.

Comment: LEt's get conventional: the printhead moves in the **X** direction on the gantry. The Gantry is lifted in **Z** by the leadscrew. The Bed moves in the **Y** direction underneath. Are you saying it stopped moving the head in X?

Comment: Yes, it's only printing like the arrows from the image in Y-axis. The head is not moving in X-axis and Z-axis

Comment: There we go! Got you some information, which might help troubleshoot or solve the problem, if you are lucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I unscrewed parts that move X and Z axis, took off E and X connectors and then put everything in place. Gently moved the head on X axis, turned the printer on and it was working fine. Maybe, something was stuck or not in place while printing previous large model.

Comment: So you followed the tests for connection and a stuck motor?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the printer stopped working in the X-direction. There can be multiple reasons for this:

- The motor is not connected to the mainboard.

  - Check the connectors. It should be plugged into the motor and the mainboard. The Ender3 is known to have its cable in such a position that it can be pulled at by the bed on some occasions, a pulled connector can happen because of that.
- The motor might be stuck.

  - Carefully try to rotate the pulley wheel on the x-axis motor while powered down. If it doesn't move, the motor might need replacement. If you move the printhead manually with a slow to medium speed you might generate current, and light up the display of the printer. Such a lighting up indicates that the motor, the connectors, and some parts of the main board are working. Be careful with this, as you generate current.
- The mainboard has a stepper driver that is damaged and won't supply voltage to the motor.

  - You'd need to get a new mainboard.